# How can I change from playing as plant to playing as zombie?

Tags: xbox-360, plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

Hi my son has just started playing this game but wants to swap from being a plant to a zombie but doesn't know how? Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Fab thank you so much he's done it and is very happy!! :)) much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are [two gamemodes you can play as a zombie in](http://help.ea.com/en/article/game-modes-in-pvz-garden-warfare/) (emphasis mine):

> **Multiplayer Mayhem: Team Vanquish**   In Team Vanquish, you choose a side and **join a team of Plants or Zombies**. Unlike other game
>   modes, you have only one objective: vanquish as many as you can from
>   the opposing team! It's a botanical brawl where you don't go tiptoeing
>   through the tulips unless you're sneaking up on someone.
>
> **Multiplayer Method: Gardens and Graveyards**   If Team Vanquish is a free-for-all, Gardens and Graveyards is a tactical assault in which
>   teamwork really will win the day! Play as a plant and defend your
>   garden stronghold, or **play as a zombie** trying to invade and
>   degrade it.

Note: Some of the gamemodes need to be unlocked before they can be played.

Answer (score 2):

When playing in any game mode except garden ops, you can change teams by pressing the left bumper on the character select screen. Note that you cannot change teams if the team you wish to play on is either full, or has too many players compared to the team you are currently on.